# OpenCv isn't returning grey value for the Apple Pencil location in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, opencv

I have this application that takes an image (under OpenCVWrapper) that is grayscale and turns the brightness of that specific section that's touched by the Apple Pencil into sound. The dark areas don't make any sound, the medium areas make a medium pitch, and the bright areas make a high pitch.

But for some reason the code works in some areas of the image flawlessly and in other it's almost reversed.

This part is called OpenCVWrapper.h it's a file in my Xcodeproject

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject
+ (UInt16) getGrayVal:(int)i :(int)j;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Then this file saved as OpenCVWrapper.mm

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
@implementation OpenCVWrapper

+ (UInt16) getGrayVal:(int)i :(int)j{
    cv::Mat grayMat;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gausshighres" ofType:@"png"];
    const char * cpath = [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    grayMat = cv::imread(cpath,cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
    return grayMat.at<UInt16>(i, j);
}
@end
```

which goes to my view controller in this line

```
let grayVal = Double(OpenCVWrapper.getGrayVal(Int32(round(y)),Int32(round(x))))
```

The x and y are location of the pen

```
        let x = pencilStrokeRecognizer.touchLocation.x
        let y = pencilStrokeRecognizer.touchLocation.y
```

Issue is that the value I get for the grayVal is straight up wrong in some spots. It calls dark areas with a large grayVal and bright areas are random. It's wrong about 50% of the time and I don't know why.

This has the full code but I figured out the problem lies within this section maybe

[Swift app's audio don't match the brightness intensity of the image section randomly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749240/swift-apps-audio-dont-match-the-brightness-intensity-of-the-image-section-rand)

[This is the image it's processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6VDd.png)

Overall it returns no errors but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

**NEW STUFF**
**This was the way I scaled the image:**

```
        //Calculate point at which pencil is touching with respect to the input image
func pencilTouchHandler(touch: UITouch) {
    //Get point at which user is touching
    let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.coordinateSpaceView)

    //Excute if touch input is within the image
    if currentPoint.x >= origin.x && currentPoint.y >= origin.y
        && currentPoint.x < (origin.x + size.width-1)
        && currentPoint.y < (origin.y + size.height-1){

        //Track whether or not touch was within the boundaries of the image
        touchInImage = true

        //Calculate (x,y) coordinates with respect to input image
        //Use ratio of original image dimensions
        let xVal = (imageSize.width / size.width)*(currentPoint.x - origin.x)
        let yVal = (imageSize.height / size.height)*(currentPoint.y - origin.y)

        //Record Touch Location
        touchLocation = CGPoint(x: xVal, y: yVal)
        lastTouch = currentPoint
    }
}
```

and then I did

```
   let x = pencilStrokeRecognizer.touchLocation.x
   let y = pencilStrokeRecognizer.touchLocation.y
```

Comment: Why are you reading from file the image every time you call your  `getGrayVal` method? Wouldn’t be better to load the image once into a member of your class? In this way, when calling `getGrayVal` method, you just look at `I` and `j` coordinates of your already loaded image. Just make sure you load the image before the first call to `getGrayVal`.

Comment: Do you know where I can find how to do that? I got this code from another developer and I'm trying to fix it. My swift and coding experience can be summed up into about a month. So I don't know much yet. Ive been just reading and I got lost on this step

Comment: Here is a link to Objective C documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html. I will try to make a sample of code, but I don’t have a Mac. Also I have little experience with Objective C.

Comment: Header:
In the interface definition, under `getGrayVal`, add:
`+ (void) loadImage;`

.mm file:
```#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
@implementation OpenCVWrapper
static cv::Mat grayMat;

+(void) loadImage
{
     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gausshighres" ofType:@"png"];
    const char * cpath = [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    grayMat = cv::imread(cpath,cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
    return grayMat.at<UInt16>(i, j);
}

+ (UInt16) getGrayVal:(int)i :(int)j{
    return grayMat.at<UInt16>(i, j);
}
@end```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the X and Y for the pencil match the X and Y for the image? I suspect not.
The image might be displayed scaled on the screen. The image might be upside down on the screen to how it is stored in memory. There might be an offset on the left or right side caused by a window coordinate system that doesn't match the screen.

To debug this, Try changing the image. Use an image with only four colors: a white square that takes a quarter of the screen, a black that is a quarter of the screen, a grey that is a quarter of the screen, etc.

You should be able to see if the image is upside down easily. You should be able to see if there is a scaling issue by finding that the transition happens in the wrong spot. Once you know what is going on you should be able to read the documentation to find out what translations are happening so you can properly map the pen x and y to the image x and y.

Comment: I added the scaling. Do you think that's the correct way to do it? Check the new stuff on the post